# Pyqt table click action error : (native Qt signal is not callable)

Tags: python, pyqt

I made a simple stock monitoring system, through Pyqt5. There are two click action when click each table, one thing is hyperlink to newssite, and the other is set some other option. Hyperlink method run well, but doubleclick method do not run with errorcode : (native Qt signal is not callable).

How can I fix it?

Here is my code. I used global variable `news_table` and `portfolio_table`

```
def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)

    def table_on_click_show_news(col):
        href = news_table.ix[col].href
        webbrowser.open(href, new=2)

    def table_on_click_chose_pf(col):
        target_pf = portfolio_table.ix[col].Portfolio_name
        print(target_pf)
```

---

```
    self.News_table.cellClicked.connect(table_on_click_show_news)

    self.Table_Current_pf1.cellDoubleClicked(table_on_click_chose_pf)
```

Comment: use `self.Table_Current_pf1.cellDoubleClicked.connect(table_on_click_chose_pf)`

Comment: @eyllanesc wow I forgot very simple thing.. thanks